# Detect if user is scrolling and changing a variable each time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I already have this:

```
var i = 0;
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
    i = i + 1;
    document.write(i.toString())
}
```

How do I change or add code to make it so that I can repeat this process infinite times, and each time `i` gets 1 added.
I need it for my website.

Comment: Is the `document.write` just for verification? If so, use `console.log()` instead and open your browser's developer console.

Comment: You'll have to describe how this code behaves that is different that what you want or expect.  I'm betting it's the `document.write()` call

Answer (score 1):

The problem with document.write is that it clears out the contents of the document, so you no longer have any content to scroll. You may notice that you no longer have scrollbars at all! So you have no scroll event either.

If you really want the output to show on the page, then create a place to output to. A disabled input works fine.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pNgS/

html:

```
<input id="scrollcount" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0" />
```

javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var scrollcount = document.getElementById('scrollcount');
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
    i = i + 1;
    scrollcount.value = i.toString();
}
```

You can test this right here and now. Open your console and run this:

```
var i = 0;
var scrollcount = $('#answer-22718395 .vote-count-post')[0];
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
    i = i + 1;
    scrollcount.innerHTML = i.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i wanted to output i everytime after i scrolled.

Comment: That's exactly what this does.

Comment: Oh... Well thank you very much then! Can I just switch i with a specific picture then?

Comment: You can do whatever your heart desires.

Comment: Tested it and it doesnt work... I get some sort of  square with a 0 in it and if i scroll nothing happens.. :/

Comment: Does your page scroll or are you just moving your scrollwheel around?

Comment: I have a mac and i just scroll around but before this worked just fine.

Comment: Ah, to update the value of an `<input>`, the attribute is `value`, not `innerHTML`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pNgS/

Comment: Cool! Now that's my last question. Is there a possibility to detect if it gets scrolled down or up? (Best would be something similar to my code.)

Comment: This can get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/6pNgS/2/. Just compare the previous scrollTop with the current scrollTop.

Comment: I might just annoy you by now but I think this doesn't work if your page is not scrollable. Basically I try to write a page where is a book that changes pages if you scroll down/up.

Answer (score 1):

That code will run every time a user scrolls if you have enough content on the page to scroll through. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUwjS/).

```
var i = 0;
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(i);
}
```

Open developer tools console and you will see that i is incremented and pushed to the console every time you scroll up or down.